# Have same right position with absolute and fixed

Tags: jquery

I have an element "#sky" which has absolute position and right position -318px.
I want to have this element fixed when I scroll but only until I reach half of page height. Then and what to have it absolute again. I have this code:

```
var elementPosition = $('#sky').offset();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
          $('#sky').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('right','0');
    } else {
        $('#sky').css({
            'right':'-318px',
            'position':'absolute'
        });
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#wrapper-bottom-new').height() / 2) {
        $('#sky').css({
            'right':'-318px',
            'position':'absolute'
        });
    }     
});
```

The problem is when it changes position to fixed I can't achieve the same right position. I have set it to 0 but it is not on the same position. Is there any way how to achieve the same result? 
[Absolute position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6D34.png)
[Fixed position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQFwR.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var elementPosition = $('#sky').offset();
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
              $('#sky').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('right','0');
        } else {
            $('#sky').css({
             'right':'-318px',
             'position':'absolute'
            });
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#wrapper-bottom-new').height() / 2) {
      $('#sky').css({
             'right':'-318px',
             'position':'absolute'
            });
    }     
});
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.middle {
  height: 3000px;
  background:red;
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  float: left;
}

.sky {
  width: 305px;
  height: 100%;
  right: -318px;
  position:absolute;
}

.w300h600 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="middle">

</div>
<div class="sky" id="sky"> 
                         <div id="w300h200" style="background-color: #190EAA;width:300px;height:200px;"></div>
       <div class="w300h300" id="w300h300" style="position: relative;">
        <div id="bmone2n-24401.1.1.10"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="w300h600" id="w300h600" style="position: relative;background-color:green">
        <div id="bmone2n-24401.1.1.6"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide more information of how it's looking right now, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or Codepen preferred.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh I added JSFiddle

Comment: Please show how you want your output to look like?

Comment: Same position but fixed when I start scroll.